# Automatic association icon to <a> according to file type not working

Tags: css, anchor, background-image

In my .css stylesheet I am trying to associate icon images (.gif) to the <a> tag's before pseudo attribute [i.e., a:before], so that whenever a specific file type is referred through its href, it displays associated icon prior to the linked text. My code is as follows:

```
a[href$=".pdf"]:before  {  
content:"";  
display:inline-block;  
width:16px;  
height:16px;  
color:#FFF;  
font-size:1em;  
font-weight:bold;  
background-color:transparent;  
background-repeat:no-repeat;  
background-attachment:fixed;  
background-position:center;  
}  
a[href$=".pdf"]:before {
background-image:url(../pics/pdf_icon.gif);
}
```

The .css file path: /css/mystyle.css
The image path: /pics/pdf_icon.gif

This block of codes is at the end of the css file, after other anchor identifiers (e.g., a:hover, a:link etc.)

The problem is that, the background image is not showing!!!

Any Help guys...?!

Comment: are you sure that you have a tag that has href attribute ending in .pdf

Answer (score 3):

Easy way to bring pdf or other icon with each link using CSS3:

**1. Using icon from FontAwesome:**

```
a[href$=".pdf"]:before
{
  content:"\f1c1  ";
  font-family: fontawesome;
}
```

**2. Using icon through background image:**

```
a[href$=".pdf"]
{
  background:url("your-image-url.png") no-repeat left;
  padding-left:25px;
}
```

Using icon

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your URL in quotes:

```
background-image:url("../pics/pdf_icon.gif");
```

A little tip - If you want to specify more than one image, separate the URLs with a comma.

Comment: I have tried using quotes mentioning the image path already. But that  is not working...

Answer (score 1):

Remove the declaration `background-attachment:fixed;`. And make sure that the document is rendered in “Standards Mode”.

Answer (score 1):

I tried removing:

> background-attachment:fixed;

and it worked.
I suppose that "fixed" with "before" don't understand where to fix it.